# How do you manage private queue permissions on a windows server 2008 cluster?

Tags: windows-server-2008, cluster, failover, msmq

On windows server 2003 there was an option to allow a resource to interact with the desktop, this allowed you to run computer management mmc snap-in on the virtual name of the cluster, allowing you to manage permissions of the private message queues on the cluster.  Windows Server 2008 failover clustering has removed that checkbox, so applications can no longer interact with the desktop.  My question is then how does one go about managing private queue permissions on the clustered (the virtual name) server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right Click on the MSMQ Cluster application and select "Manage MSMQ". this will launch a Computer management window in which the cluster MSMQs can be managed.